# date function with strtotime is going to last sunday, but i want it to be most recent sunday

Tags: php

I have the following line of code

```
$sunday = date ("m/d", strtotime("last sunday"));
$saturday = date("m/d",strtotime("this saturday"));
```

but if today is sunday, it will not select today.  The rest of the week will be fine, because last sunday would be today.  I was thinking to do like:

```
if (today is not sunday) {set to last sunday }else{ set to today }
```

similarly for saturday.

**Edit:**

It it acceptable to do something like, or is there a better way:

```
$today = date('D', strtotime("today"));
if( $today === 'Sun') {
    $sunday = date ("m/d", strtotime("today"));
}else{
    $sunday = date ("m/d", strtotime("last sunday"));
}

if ( $today === "Sat"){
    $saturday =  date ("m/d", strtotime("today"));
}else{
    $saturday = date("m/d",strtotime("this saturday"));
}
```

Comment: The definition of the word "last" comes into play here. If today is sunday, then "last sunday" is not today, like in a real conversation. You would not go home and tell your wife "Last sunday I came home just now and told you something". This is a logical error really

Comment: Using a ternary is easier `$sunday = date('D', strtotime("today")) == 'Sun' ? strtotime("today") : strtotime("last sunday");`

Comment: @MarkBaker Easier still, though arguably less readable: `$sunday = strtotime(date('D') == 'Sun' ? 'today' : 'last sunday')`

Comment: Surely almost anything would be better than 7 IFs.

Comment: lol, yea i normally do ternary, but i wanted it human readable.  Luckily though, im not doing 7 ifs, because there is nothing relevant to the other 5 days.   It just seems that there was just an issue at the start and end of the week for the code i was working with.

Comment: Ah, well, I think all our answers are a bit ugly, but you can hide the ugly in a function with a human readable comment :) My answer rather assumed you were after 7 days, so maybe having a saturday and a sunday function is better then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure you could have come up with this yourself really, but...

What about:

```
function today_or_lastday ($day) {
    return date('m/d', strtotime("7 days ago")) == date('m/d', strtotime("last $day"))
        ? date('m/d', strtotime("today"))
        : date('m/d', strtotime("last $day"));
}
```

And:

```
$sunday = today_or_lastday("sunday");
$saturday = today_or_lastday("saturday");
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a line like this to get the last/current Saturday and Sunday:

```
$sunday   = date( 'm/d', time() - ( date( 'w' ) * 3600*24 ) );
$saturday = date( 'm/d', time() - ( ( date( 'w' ) + 1 ) % 7 * 3600*24 ) );
```

For Sunday we take now - days from Sunday.

date( 'w' ) gives us the weekday (0=Sunday, 1=Monday, ... 6=Saturday) and we subtract the number of days (counted in seconds 3600*24 ) that has past since Sunday.

For Saturday we do the same thing, but add a little maths trickery to adjust for it being day 6.